# ssh_config Bad Configuration Option Error

Tags: ssh, mac-osx

Please help. I've read so many topics of not-quite-the-same problem and none of them have guided me to my answer.  When trying to connect to a server using any FTP client, I get this error:

```
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 2: Bad configuration option: 2020/07/17
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
```

I've enclosed a screenshot of my ssh_config file.  What do I need to change and how do I change it?

For context, I'm running MacOSX Ventura and this started happening when I upgraded from whatever the last OS was.

[Image #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4i5D.png)

[Image #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EIe4.jpg)

Comment: Please, don't post screenshots of text you could just copy&paste. You are just making it harder for people to extract information from it.

Comment: I literally went to the effort of taking those 2 screenshots because in so many of these threads there is a catty, sarcastic person like you throwing snide remarks like "Why couldn't you have included a screenshot so we can actually see what's going on".  

If I had not included the screenshots I would bet my last dollar that someone would have responded with the opposite of what you have said.  Ugh, you people.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message the problem is in line 2.

Line 2 starts with `2022/07/...`.

It is missing the `#` character to mark it as a comment.